# Selecting parent and child to find span

Tags: html, typescript, model-view-controller, selector

Im trying to show a span upon clicking a button. Hiding the button itself works perfectly but now im trying to show the phonenumber by selecting the span from the curentTarget. I tried it like this but its not working.

```
<li class="phonenumber">
<em class="fa fa-clock-o text-blue"></em>
<button type="button">Telefonnummer anzeigen</button>
<span class="phonenumberspan" style="display:none">phone</span> 
</li>
```

As mentioned, the hiding of the button works but somehome the selection from the currentTarget to the span is wrong. Thanks for any help.

```
private _showPhoneNr(e: Event) {
        var target = $(e.currentTarget);
        target.hide();
        var parent = target.parent("phonenumber");
        var number = parent.find("phonenumberspan");
        number.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

to select a parent element you can use this in your code

`var number = document.getElementsByClassName('phonenumberspan')[0].parentElement.nodeName;`

Comment: i need to select it from the currentTarget because there are multiple of these so i need to navigate from the target